# How to prevent @param types from becoming broken links

Tags: jsdoc3

When generating docs, the type "string" (among others) will become a link to "string.html" which does not exist. How do we prevent that from happening? I want plain text to show for these types.

```
/**
 * the comment
 *
 * @param {string} myString
 */
```

config:

```
"opts": {
    "encoding": "utf8",
    "recurse": true,
    "destination": "out/clean/",
    "template": "./node_modules/clean-jsdoc-theme/"
},
"tags": {
    "allowUnknownTags": false,
    "dictionaries": ["jsdoc","closure"]
},
"source": {
    "includePattern": ".+\\.js?$",
    "include": ["path/to/file"]
},
"plugins": ["plugins/markdown"],
"markdown": {
    "hardwrap": false,
    "idInHeadings": true
}
```

Comment: turn off autocompletion features in your feature rich ide

Comment: @Joe What do you mean?

Comment: Its autocompleting for you and taking your #string refs as html or converting it as you type or click

Comment: I am not sure if I follow. The comment looks the same in my IDE as it does in my text editor.

Comment: Open that bad boy up in nano or vim

Comment: It looks as you can see above when viewing the file in nano.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was that I had a "@memberof string", which then jsdoc made a "string.html" file out of.